# google certificates correct CA

Tags: tls, certificates, certificate-authority, google, x.509

I view certificates of https://www.google.com.ua/

[image]

So I thought, when requesting via cURL, if I point by `CURLOPT_CAINFO` to those certificates (`GeoTrust Global CA` and `Google Internet Authority G2` in a bundle or whatever), the validation of google's certificate would be passed. But the only CA that does it is the `Equifax Secure CA` (discovered it by plain enumeration of git's `CA bundle`). Could someone explain why is it so? Thanks a lot.

UPD: it's not only google's behaviour, another site behaves that way too, so I suppose either I misinterpret something (which is likely) or some wrong information is being shown (again, why is this happening)

Answer (score 5):

**This is most likely an obsolete "bridge" now leading to the wrong place.**

There are two valid trust chains for this cert. There is a root cert for GeoTrust Global CA, valid from 2002, which is in current Windows/IE and Firefox stores (and Java); and also a "cross-signed" cert for that CA under Equifax Global CA as follows:

```
Data:
    Version: 3 (0x2)
    Serial Number: 1227750 (0x12bbe6)
Signature Algorithm: sha1WithRSAEncryption
    Issuer: C=US, O=Equifax, OU=Equifax Secure Certificate Authority
    Validity
        Not Before: May 21 04:00:00 2002 GMT
        Not After : Aug 21 04:00:00 2018 GMT
    Subject: C=US, O=GeoTrust Inc., CN=GeoTrust Global CA
    Subject Public Key Info: <snipped: same as root>
   X509v3 extensions:
        X509v3 Authority Key Identifier:
            keyid:48:E6:68:F9:2B:D2:B2:95:D7:47:D8:23:20:10:4F:33:98:90:9F:D4
        X509v3 Subject Key Identifier:
            C0:7A:98:68:8D:89:FB:AB:05:64:0C:11:7D:AA:7D:65:B8:CA:CC:4E
        X509v3 Basic Constraints: critical
            CA:TRUE
        X509v3 Key Usage: critical
            Certificate Sign, CRL Sign
        X509v3 CRL Distribution Points:
            Full Name:
              URI:http://crl.geotrust.com/crls/secureca.crl
        X509v3 Certificate Policies:
            Policy: X509v3 Any Policy
              CPS: https://www.geotrust.com/resources/repository
<snip signature>
```

This is apparently a "bridge" cert, often used when a renamed (here) or new CA root is created and wants to temporarily leverage the existing trust of an older CA root; the Equifax root is valid from 1998 so in say 1999 and 2000 there were lots of clients that would know the Equifax root and not the GeoTrust root. 12 years later it should be obsolete.

Running 'openssl s_client' confirms www.google.com.ua is providing in the SSL handshake its own cert, the Google Internet Authority G2 intermediate cert, and the bridge cert. IE, FF, and Java are all smart enough to ignore the bridge and use the GeoTrust root which they have internally stored. OpenSSL, which curl uses, is not, or at least not yet; thus you must tell curl to give OpenSSL the Equifax root. (The OpenSSL 1.0.2 release, currently in beta, is announced to have enhancements in the area of cert chain validation, which I haven't looked at in detail yet.)

**EDIT 3/13:** I can't comment on my answer(!) so adding here. As I said,
there are TWO certs for GeoTrust Global CA: one root, and one "bridge".

IE/Windows and FF **DO** have the GeoTrust root; you already saw it in Certification Path in IE or FF with the webpage open, or you can look directly in the truststores with InternetOptions/Content/Certificates/TrustedRoots and Tools/Options/Advanced/Certificates/Authorities. Both **also** have the Equifax root, but don't use it here. Both IE and FF display the certification path **used** even though it differs from what the server **sent**; that may be "wrong" in one way of looking but "right" in another.

A root cert is always self-signed; that's necessary to be a root (not always for an anchor, but leave that aside). The GeoTrust root cert is a root. The GeoTrust bridge cert is not a root, it links to the Equifax root cert which is a root. And, again, the Equifax root is the one curl + openssl needs.

**EDIT 9/01:** https://knowledge.geotrust.com/support/knowledge-base/index?page=content&id=AR1426&actp=search&viewlocale=en_US&searchid=1283360269668 confirms this is a bridge cert back to Equifax.

**UPDATE 2017/03/28**: first, OpenSSL 1.0.2 did add `-trusted_first` which uses the GeoTrust root if present and ignores the bridge cert. Second, this is now more important because the Equifax root has been removed from the Mozilla/NSS truststore, and thus the curl-project CAfile used by many clients, see https://serverfault.com/a/841071/216633 .

Comment: I checked certificates and got:
`Equifax Secure Certificate Authority:
    Data:
        Version: 3 (0x2)
        Serial Number: 903804111 (0x35def4cf)
    Signature Algorithm: sha1WithRSAEncryption
        Issuer: C=US, O=Equifax, OU=Equifax Secure Certificate Authority
        Validity
            Not Before: Aug 22 16:41:51 1998 GMT
            Not After : Aug 22 16:41:51 2018 GMT
        Subject: C=US, O=Equifax, OU=Equifax Secure Certificate Authority
        ...`

Comment: `GeoTrust Global CA:
    Data:
        Version: 3 (0x2)
        Serial Number: 144470 (0x23456)
    Signature Algorithm: sha1WithRSAEncryption
        Issuer: C=US, O=GeoTrust Inc., CN=GeoTrust Global CA
        Validity
            Not Before: May 21 04:00:00 2002 GMT
            Not After : May 21 04:00:00 2022 GMT
        Subject: C=US, O=GeoTrust Inc., CN=GeoTrust Global CA
...`

Comment: Tried `openssl s_client`:
`depth=2 C = US, O = GeoTrust Inc., CN = GeoTrust Global CA
verify error:num=20:unable to get local issuer certificate
verify return:0
---
Certificate chain
 0 s:/C=US/ST=California/L=Mountain View/O=Google Inc/CN=google.com
   i:/C=US/O=Google Inc/CN=Google Internet Authority G2
 1 s:/C=US/O=Google Inc/CN=Google Internet Authority G2
   i:/C=US/O=GeoTrust Inc./CN=GeoTrust Global CA
 2 s:/C=US/O=GeoTrust Inc./CN=GeoTrust Global CA
   i:/C=US/O=Equifax/OU=Equifax Secure Certificate Authority
---`
and that verify error is an exact error cURL gave.

Comment: What I'm trying to say is that `GeoTrust Global CA` is not an actual root CA. Windows just has that `Equifax` certificate. You say "12 years later it should be obsolete", but it is actually not. And the information displayed turns out to be incorrect. Am I right?

Comment: Another site I checked
`---
Certificate chain
 0 s:/OU=Domain Control Validated/CN=id.tmtm.ru
   i:/C=US/ST=Arizona/L=Scottsdale/O=GoDaddy.com, Inc./OU=http://certs.godaddy.com/repository//CN=Go Daddy Secure Certificate Authority - G2
 1 s:/C=US/ST=Arizona/L=Scottsdale/O=GoDaddy.com, Inc./OU=http://certs.godaddy.com/repository//CN=Go Daddy Secure Certificate Authority - G2
   i:/C=US/ST=Arizona/L=Scottsdale/O=GoDaddy.com, Inc./CN=Go Daddy Root Certificate Authority - G2...`

Comment: `...
 2 s:/C=US/ST=Arizona/L=Scottsdale/O=GoDaddy.com, Inc./CN=Go Daddy Root Certificate Authority - G2
   i:/C=US/ST=Arizona/L=Scottsdale/O=GoDaddy.com, Inc./CN=Go Daddy Root Certificate Authority - G2
---`

It seems to be fine when a root certificate is self-signed. But when it is not, there has to be a certificate of the issuer.

Comment: Thanks, this helped me figure out why the GeoTrust SSL checker was suggesting that I add this old Equifax certificate to the chain. I agree, shouldn't be needed any more. I've blogged my understanding of the issue:  http://www.mcbsys.com/techblog/2014/06/care-and-feeding-of-your-rapidssl-certificate-on-aws/.